# Checking feasibility with eigenvalue and linear constraints

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Is there an efficient algorithm to check the simultaneous feasibility  of linear and eigenvalue constraints? For example,  given $ \lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge 0$, is the following problem efficiently solvable : Are there $a_{ij} \ge 0$ such that

(i) $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}=1$ such that $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$.

(ii) Largest eigenvalue of the matrix $A = [a_{ij}] = \lambda_1 $

(iii) All other eigenvalues of $A$ are upper bounded by $\lambda_2$ in magnitude.

It is okay if constraints (ii) and (iii) are satisfied with $\epsilon$ error.

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: Yes, A is symmetric. I added the condition now.

Comment: It seems to me that this might not be writable as an SDP---but I haven't had time to think about it properly yet.

Comment: I feel that if $\lambda_1$ is small enough, then there should always be a matrix that satisfies these constraints; the $a_{ij} \ge 0$ is the twist seems to make things harder....